# Unknown coordinate system warning when programmatically adding layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcobjects, coordinate-system

I have another interesting question for you.

I have data with unknown coordinate system.
When I add this data using a standard tool(File->Add Data) in ArcMap, a warning dialog appears.
It looks like:

[image: warning dialog]

But this dialog didn't appears if I add data programmatically using arcobjects.
Is there a way to show this dialog, if I add layers programmatically?

P.S. I found DatumCheckerClass, but that's not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to check manually and show your own warning.

```
IGeoDataset IGS = (IGeoDataset)pFeatureClass;
if (IGS.SpatialReference.Name == "Unknown")
{
   MessageBox.show("Unknown Spatial Reference....");
}
```

I searched for this dialog myself some time ago, but never found a solution.